# Return entities where HasMany association collection count is 0 using QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have 2 entities, Parent and Child.

```
Parent
-Children (has many)

Child
-parent_id
```

Now I want to get all Parents that have 0 children.

I want to use QueryOver to get this List result.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing the following query should do it..

```
Session.QueryOver<Parent>()..WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Children).IsEmpty.List();
```